# Query by example for Locked Out Accounts in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory

I would like to use query by example to show me all the locked out accounts in my OU.

I was able to successfully do something similar with Enabled accounts and also Smart Card Logon Required accounts.

For some reason, `userPrincipal.IsAccountLockedOut()` seems to function different than `userPrincipal.Enabled`

Basically , it seems to be a method rather than a variable.

I searched online and couldn't find any relevant answers or documentation specific to this use case.

Here is my code, currently:

```
bool enabled = true;
bool locked = false;
string firstName = "John";
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

up.Enabled = enabled;

up.GivenName = firstName;
```

But,  `up.IsAccountLockedOut() = locked;`  doesn't work. Neither does `locked = up.IsAccountLockedOut()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsAccountLockedOut()` functions differently than `Enabled` since those are two different things:

- An account is locked out by too many wrong password attempts. This is to prevent brute force attempts to guess a password. Accounts are usually automatically unlocked after a period of time. The number of wrong attempts that triggers a lockout and the time before automatic unlocking is configurable by the domain admin.
- Disabling an account (`Enabled == false`) is when an administrator has specifically disabled the account. No one will be able to authenticate with a disabled account, even if they know the right password.

To find locked out accounts, you want to look at the [`lockoutTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adls/eb73820d-907a-49a5-a6f3-1847f86629b4) attribute. It stores the time the account was locked out. A value of 0 means it's not locked. So you want to look for accounts where the value is greater than 0. This would be the LDAP query:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(lockoutTime>=1))
```

You have to use `>=1` since the LDAP spec doesn't actually support `>`.

I assume you're asking this question since you're trying to search with `PrincipalSearcher`, which limits you to searching based on properties that `UserPrincipal` exposes to you. Since the `lockoutTime` attribute is not exposed by `UserPrincipal`, you can't do it that way. You'll have to use `DirectorySearcher` directly (which is what `PrincipalSearcher` uses behind the scenes anyway). Here is an example that would output the username and the time that the lockout occurred:

```cs
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher() {
    Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(lockoutTime>=1))",
    PageSize = 1000, //make sure we get more than one page, if needed
    PropertiesToLoad = { "sAMAccountName", "lockoutTime" } //which atrributes you want to use
};

using (var results = searcher.FindAll()) {

    foreach (SearchResult result in results)     {
        var username = (string) result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0];

        var lockoutTime = DateTime.FromFileTime((long) result.Properties["lockoutTime"][0]);

        Console.WriteLine($"{username} was locked out at {lockoutTime}");
    }
}
```

Personally, I've stopped using `UserPrincipal`/`PrincipalSearcher` altogether because performance is always worse (sometimes it's not noticeable, other times it absolutely is), and there are times like this when you can't use it anyway. I wrote an article about getting the best performance when talking to AD, if you're interested: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

Comment: While we are on the topic, can I get the computer name that locked out the user?

Comment: @AviParshan You would have to look in the Event Log of the domain controller to find that. It's not stored on the account.